# jQuery highlight matched elements with live() or on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVermeulen/26VeD/37/) example can you see that I made a button where I add some elements and links to delete this elements. In this example it is not about going to delete the elements, but to hover the (remove)link made by clicking the button so it highlights the element with the same "number" attribute.

I have tried to use `live();` and `on();` for it, but it does not do anything, because the items are made after building the page.

I prefer to use `on();` now because jQuery says:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

**My jQuery code:**

```
    function numbers() {
        return $('#links span').length;
    }

    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        $('#links').append('<span number="' + (numbers() + 1) + '">Remove element ' + (numbers() + 1) + '</span><br />');
        $('#elements').append('<div number="' + numbers() + '" class="element">Element ' + numbers() + '</div>');
    });

    $('#links span').live('hover', function () {
        var number = $(this).attr('number');
        if ($('#elements .element').attr('number') == number) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }

});
```

Comment: Have you read `on()` documentation?!

Comment: Instead of appending, you could just include them in your page, but use visibility:hidden or display:none

Comment: @Sidetik No because I need to add them. So it can ben 10 elements by also 80.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should dynamically bind the events, since the elements are added dynamically. Second of all, you should make use of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, since you want to toggle the highlighting and need to know when the cursor is leaving the element. And third of all I recommend using `data-`-attributes instead of a custom attribute called `number`.

```
function numbers() {
    return $("#links span").length;
}

$("#add").on("click", function () {
    var number = numbers() + 1;
    $("#links").append("<span data-number='" + number + "'>Remove element " + number + "</span><br />");
    $("#elements").append("<div data-number='" + number + "' class='element'>Element " + number + "</div>");
});

// Dynamically bind mouseenter and mouseleave events, so they also apply to dynamically added elements
$("body").on("mouseenter", "#links span", function () {
    var number = $(this).data("number");
    $(".element[data-number='" + number + "']").addClass("highlight");
}).on("mouseleave", "#links span", function () {
    var number = $(this).data("number");
    $(".element[data-number='" + number + "']").removeClass("highlight");
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/26VeD/43/)**

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and explanation!